# Difference between PIN encryption key variant and data encryption key variant

Tags: encryption, cryptography, 3des, dukpt

In the process of decryption a data, I am getting this two definitions confused. I would really appreciate a better understanding to these two different description.

Already searched google, to see if i can get more understanding, but still confused with the ones i got.

Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WRT DUKPT key varients:

Here is a table that shows the DUKPT variants.  You really should get ANSI X9.24, Part 1 [document](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ANSI+X9.24-1%3A2009&sourcekeyword=_inurl%3Awebstore.ansi.org%23inurl%3Asku%3Dansi%2Bx9&source=google&adgroup=x9&gclid=CKPp4pmItc8CFRJbhgodWHMCEw) and read the DUKPT section.

[image]